# Save data on multiple tables using Java JBDC CacheRowSet?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, rowset, cachedrowset

As the question above. Can I save data to multiple tables at a time on a CachedRowSet using a JOIN query statement?

Sample sql query statement as below

> SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN class ON student.class_id = class.id

Is it possible or should I use JoinRowSet or something else instead? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JoinRowSet

Refer http://www.visualbuilder.com/java/jdbc/tutorial/joinrowset/

Using 2 CachedRowSet is also achievable. But data integrity will not be assured.

Also for more details refer

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/cachedrowset.html